docx openxml file format, and rendering lists special cases
I have had a look at this article The MSDN article Working with Numbered Lists in Open XML WordprocessingML discusses the issue in detail
it describes how to render lists inside of a docx file, but in fact when implementing it kind of fails for some cases.
for example a list might have 2 items with different numIds, and it seems that ms-word is able to handle that and extract the correct numbering while I can't do that.
I wish if there is another document or there is a public code describing how ms-word or libre office writter handles different types of lists with special cases. (something like a high fidelty output of docx)

here is a description of a case from a document I have
is that the numId differes among paragraphs belonging to the same list
for example
as shown below is that the level 1 and level 2 list items have the same numId here
<w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000000C">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
                <w:numPr>
                    <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
                    <w:numId w:val="1"/>
                </w:numPr>
                <w:ind w:left="680" w:hanging="680"/>
                <w:rPr/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_heading=h.1fob9te" w:id="2"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="2"/>
            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Definitions and interpretation</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000000D">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
                <w:numPr>
                    <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
                    <w:numId w:val="1"/>
                </w:numPr>
                <w:ind w:left="680" w:hanging="680"/>
                <w:rPr/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_heading=h.3znysh7" w:id="3"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="3"/>
            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Definitions</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
 

but the level 2 item below has a numId=5 although it belongs to the same list.
    <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000036">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
            <w:ind w:left="680" w:hanging="680"/>
            <w:rPr/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_heading=h.2et92p0" w:id="4"/>
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="4"/>
        <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">General interpretation</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>

